# how to modify textfile using U-SQL

Tags: text, jobs, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a large file of around 130MB containing 10 A characters in each line and \t at the end of 10th "A" character, I want to extract this text file and then change all A's to B's. Can any one help with its code snippet?

this is what I have wrote till now

```
USE DATABASE imodelanalytics;

@searchlog =
 EXTRACT characters string
 FROM "/iModelAnalytics/Samples/Data/dummy.txt"
 USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: '\t', skipFirstNRows: 1);


@modify = 
SELECT characters  AS line
FROM @searchlog;

OUTPUT @modify 
TO "/iModelAnalytics/Samples/Data/B.txt" 
USING Outputters.Text();
```

I'm new to this, so any suggestions will be helpful ! Thanks

Comment: Can you post a part of the file content so we can see he exact structure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the field would be `AAAAAAAAAA` then you could write:

```
@modify = SELECT "BBBBBBBBBB" AS characters FROM @searchlog;
```

If only some are all `A`s, then you would do it in the `SELECT` clause:

```
@modify = 
  SELECT (characters == "AAAAAAAAAA" ? "BBBBBBBBBB" : characters) AS characters 
  FROM @searchlog;
```

If there are other characters around the `AAAAAAAAAA` then you would use more of the C# string functions to find them and replace them in a similar pattern.

Comment: Thanks It worked, any idea now if I want to do it for all the alphabets in one job, like for it first replace all A's with B's and save to B.txt and then replace all A's with C's and save it to C.txt and so on.

Comment: Can you phrase this as a new question with sample inputs and output? Or extrapolate the above C# ternary statement to the alphabet you want to process? Also, there are other threads here that talk about how to do data driven partitioned output. The feature that will make that easier is in private preview.